# Iterate through Hashmap using Entryset

Tags: java, dictionary

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List>> entry:Map1.entrySet()) 
{
    String key=entry.getKey();
    System.out.println("Type : " +key);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry1 : entry.getKey().getValue().entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Type : " + entry1.getKey());
    }
}
```

I don't know what should be used in place of `entry.getKey().getValue().entrySet()`. Can any one explains me to understand this. This is for iterating nested map.

the error I got was

```
.\common\devtracker\process\devtr\DevTrackerImpl.java:226: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getValue()
location: class java.lang.String
for (Map.Entry<String, List<ProjectBreakupVO>>    entry1:entry.getKey().getValue().entrySet())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

entry.getKey() does not have the method getValue(), as its just returning a string. What you probably want here

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry1 : entry.getKey().getValue().entrySet())
```

is instead to do

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry1 : entry.getValue().entrySet())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using....

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry1 : entry.getKey().getValue().entrySet())
```

to fetch the entries for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to iterate through map of type `Map<String, List>`, and you are facing **findbugs** issues when you used `myMap.keySet()` like so:

```
    for (String keyValue : myMap.keySet()) {
        String key = keyValue;
        List objValue = myMap.get(key);
    }
```

then try iterating through the map using `myMap.entrySet()` which is more recommended:

```
    for(Map.Entry<String, List> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List objValue = entry.getValue();
    }
```

So nesting forloop in this case would be like:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List>> entry:Map1.entrySet()) 
{
    String key=entry.getKey();
    System.out.println("Type : " +key);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry1 : entry.getValue().entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Type : " + entry1.getKey());
    }
}
```